# Specific inputs to be accepted with HTML5

Tags: html, input

I have these particular set of requirements that have to be met only with the use of HTML5 input pattern, and not JavaScript.

•   First Name and Last Name must be at least 2 characters, and it must start with capital letter.

•   Phone number must use Australian format: +61xx-xxxx xxxx

•   Only accept organization email address: name@organisation.org.auy

I'm new to HTML5, and I've tried some patterns, but none of them work perfectly. If someone could help.
Again only HTML5 allowed, no JavaScript.

Comment: Please show any research you've done, or things you've tried. For instance, there is an `input type="email"` added in HTML5 (research), and it would be good to see the patterns you've tried, so that we don't suggest a pattern you've attempted, but didn't find worked "perfectly".

Answer (score 0):

the pattern input accepts a general regular expression, the same type as would be used in javascript.

an aussie phone number regex would be pretty simple:

```
\+61[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}
```

in words, start with "+61", then 2 characters in 0-9, then a "-", then 4 characters 0-9, then a space, then 4 more characters 0-9, though from a UX perspective, if it MUST begin with +61 it seems silly to make the user type it.

a regex for min 2 letters, first capital would be pretty simple as well

```
[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+
```

in words, one or more capital letter characters, followed by one or more of upper or lower case characters.

the email regex is very complex, but a simple one covering most cases is:

```
[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

the input type email also covers most use cases though.